# Keep windows from going off-screen

Tags: windows, window-manager

Very simply, I was wondering if there's a way to keep windows from going off-screen. I want to be able to quickly drag a window all the way to the right and have it automatically be "docked" to the right side, without half of it going off of the visible screen. I don't think there is a Windows registry hack for this, so I'm trying to find a 3rd-party utility. I'm using Windows 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[allSnap](http://ivanheckman.com/allsnap/) - windows automatically snap to desktop edges and (optionally) the edges of other windows

Comment: This seems like exactly what I need (it even has a "Constrain windows to screen" option), but it doesn't seem to work for me. I'm running Windows 7 64-bit, and I tried both the 32-bit and 64-bit versions. Any idea why this might be? It works on the settings window of the actual program, but not on anything else.

Comment: Nevermind, apparently the 32-bit version only works with 32-bit programs, and vice-versa, and you can't run both at the same time. :/ Bummer. And it doesn't look like they're going to fix this anytime soon, because the last update was back in 2005. :(

Comment: Just tried it again (apparently they updated it), and although the problem I mentioned hasn't gone away, I can now run both the 32-bit and 64-bit versions at the same time, so it works. :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the Windows 7 feature of docking to top/bottom/left/right edges? Just grab the window and take it to any of these hot spots and leave the window.

Comment: Yes but this resizes the window and I don't want that.

Answer (score 1):

You want to snap windows to the screen edges, correct?
I haven't tried, but it looks like [this could help you](http://www.ntwind.com/software/windowspace.html).
It's Vista compatible so I guess Win7 works, too.

Comment: Great program, but it's commercial. :( Although I didn't say it had to be free in the question, so +1 anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like [Pitaschio](http://www.askvg.com/pitaschio-a-free-utility-to-customize-windows-and-desktop-experience/) has this feature, among other things.

**Edit:** Revisiting it a year later, it seems to be really buggy with 64-bit applications.

Answer (score 0):

Autohotkey could do this; I'd make the script but I have very little experience with it's window management functions - just enough to know it could pull this off.